# Running executable jar with Log4j under Ubuntu 14

Tags: java, ubuntu, jar, log4j

I use Log4J in my Java Application to log some stuff, when the application runs. I started it on my `Ubuntu 14` `VPS` with the `"nohup java -jar application.jar &"` command to keep it alive, even when I close the terminal.

As long, as the terminal is open the application logs in the logfile, when I close the terminal it doesn't. But it is still running.

**My log4j.xml:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">
<log4j:configuration debug="true"
  xmlns:log4j='http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/'>

    <appender name="console" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="file" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="append" value="true" />
        <param name="maxFileSize" value="10MB" />
        <param name="maxBackupIndex" value="10" />
        <param name="file" value="LOG/connect.log" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" 
            value="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="console" />
        <appender-ref ref="file" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

How I start the jar:

```
nohup java -jar application.jar &
```

Answer (score 0):

I too had a similar issue in ubuntu 12.04 , I fixed it by adding the executable as a service with respawn enabled instead of using nohup. Create a .conf file in the /etc/init/ folder of the os.

```
start on runlevel [2345]
respawn
exec /usr/bin/java -jar /path/to/jar
```

start and stop service manually using service serviceName stop and service serviceName start

Comment: How do I add the executable as a service with respawn enabled?

Comment: to start or stop manually, use sudo start servicename and
sudo stop servicename respectively

Comment: Okay, will try that!

Comment: Stays the process and the service alive, when I close my terminal?
Or is a "nohup" required?

Comment: nohup is not required, just the java -jar exectuable.jar portion is required

Comment: I created the following service.conf:

start on runlevel [2345]

exec java -jar ~/../application/application.jar &

When I do:
service service start

I Just get:
service stop/waiting and nothing happens